# Change cursor to wait before an Ajax petition is sent

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following JavaScript function, which is executed when a button is clicked:

```
function calculate(resource) {
    document.getElementById('loading-label').innerHTML = 'Calculating...';
    $.ajax({
        url: resource,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            document.body.style.cursor('wait');
        },
        complete: function () {
            document.body.style.cursor('default');
        }
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data == true) {
            document.getElementById('loading-label').innerHTML = 'Done!';
            document.getElementById('loading-label').style.color = 'green';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('loading-label').innerHTML = 'Error!';
            document.getElementById('loading-label').style.color = 'red';
        }
    });
}
```

But it doesn't work as I want. Maybe because I'm not using `beforeSend` and `complete` callbacks properly.

As it can be seen, when the button is clicked, a label changes its content and I would like to change the cursor to ***waiting*** until the synchronous call is finished (and then return to ***default***). How could I do that?

Comment: .cursor is not a function. `document.body.style.cursor= 'wait';` But I suggest you change a class instead - why mix DOM and jQuery?

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` is nonsense. You're making a GET request. There's no request body to describe the type of.

Comment: Errors fixed. Sorry! I'm not familiar with JS/HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't when you make a non-async request.

Aside from your trivial error (you need to **assign** new values to `cursor` with `=`, it isn't a function).

Synchronous requests **block the event loop** (which is why they are deprecated). Since the event loop is blocked, the browser doesn't perform a repaint, and the cursor doesn't change.

Write asynchronous code instead.

```
function calculate(resource) {
    document.getElementById('loading-label').innerHTML = 'Calculating...';
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    $.ajax({
        url: resource,
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data == true) {
            document.getElementById('loading-label').innerHTML = 'Done!';
            document.getElementById('loading-label').style.color = 'green';
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('loading-label').innerHTML = 'Error!';
            document.getElementById('loading-label').style.color = 'red';
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the trivial error, I'm not very familiar with JS and HTML. Just a question: what if I add a timeout to the ajax request keeping it sync? The browser would have time to repaint? This is because I would preferably need the function to be synchronous.

Comment: I can't think of any possible benefit for being synchronous that wouldn't be lost with the addition of `setTimeout`.